# How to close the websocket in graphql config flutter?

Tags: flutter, websocket, graphql, flutter-web, graphql-subscriptions

```
 class GraphqlConfig {
 final serverLink = Link.split(
      (request) => request.isSubscription,
      WebSocketLink(
        "mylink"
      ),
      HttpLink("mylink",
          defaultHeaders: <String, String>{
          
          }));

  initClient() {
    ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        link: serverLink,
        cache: GraphQLCache(),
      ),
    );
    
return client;
  }

 GraphQLClient clientToQuery() {
    return GraphQLClient(
      cache: GraphQLCache(),
      link: serverLink,
    );
  }
}
```

I got the following exception

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'close' on 'WebSocket': The code must be either 1000, or between 3000 and 4999. 1001 is neither.
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call

```
client.dispose();
```

and

```
websocketLink.dispose();
```